# "Control and certainty over / of"

Tags: word-choice

Is any or both of the following correct English?

- *The software gives you full control and certainty **over** the execution of the search.*
- *The software gives you full control and certainty **of** the execution of the search.*

A Google search for *"control and certainty over"* gives 39,000 results, a search for *"control and certainty of"* gives 127,000 results.

Comment: They are both correct. “Certainty of” appears to be more commonly used.

Comment: Great, that's what the Google search also suggests. I somehow think "over" is better, maybe since "of" appears 2 times otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure the word "certainty" really makes sense there.

Comment: @alphabet, I mean that the user can be certain that the search is executed as he expects.

Comment: Isn't that implied by full control?

Comment: I don't think that "certainty" can have that meaning in this context.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173463/control-on-vs-control-over

Comment: @Eilia Although the questions you linked are related, I do not see how they answer my question, they are about quite different phrases with different meanings.

Comment: @Barmar In a way, it is. I now also thinks it would be better to just omit "and certainty".

Comment: @alphabet Yes, it feels a bit strange to me also.